# How to fetch all open positions of binance futures through Binance api

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

How to fetch all open positions of binance futures (not only my account data) through Binance API ?

Answer (score -1):

```
Position_Information = client.futures_position_information()

positions = [i['symbol'] for i in Position_Information if float(i['positionAmt']) > 0]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).